# Activity Feed using polymorphic association can't get a :dependent => :destroy to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, feed, enumeration, polymorphic-associations

I have a model used to generate the activity feed called Activity which has the following columns:

```
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "source_id",     :null => false
t.integer  "activity_type", :null => false
t.text     "data",          :null => false
```

I'm trying to attach each activity to the different types of objects worth showing in the feed (e.g. added to favorites, new connections, etc). The following associations exist now:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :source, :polymorphic => true
```

I'm trying to use `source_id` as the primary key of the connecting object (e.g. favorites) and `activity_type` as an enum (e.g. favorites => 1, invitations =>2) using the simple_enum gem.

QUESTION: I can't get a `:dependent => :destroy` to work on the Favorites model. It reminds me in an exception that I don't have a favorites_id foreign key for it to cleanly remove an Activity once I delete a Favorite. How can I handle this?

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  column activities.favorite_id does not exist'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the activity_type field should have been called source_type, that way Rails can deal with the polymorphic stuff automatically, and you won't need manually control it's value with enums.

Comment: Yes this is right. I should have looked at the Rails Guides for this - it's very straightforward there. Thanks!